# How to prevent other people to unsubscribe on behalf of the subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, cloudpage, unsubscribe

Is it possible for a person other than subscriber to unsubscribe for them. For instance, assuming subscriber receive a email with button to that redirect it to a cloudpage with unsubscribe link on it, and when it clicked, which will unsubscribe the user. But what if someone else other than subscriber, got the link, and unsubscribe for the subscriber, is this possible? If it’s possible, how to prevent it happening?

Answer (score 7):

You can't prevent this. Should I forward my email to you, you will indeed be able to click the Unsubscribe link, and unsubscribe on my behalf.

There are no recommended ways of preventing it, but there are few options, if you really want to annoy your subscribers (and probably also violate your local legislation):

- You can trigger an email, asking the recipient to confirm his intent to unsubscribe. Since this is a new email, it will require the actual "owner" of the email address to confirm the unsubscribe.
- You can secure the unsubscribe page in a password protected profile center.

As mentioned beforehand, none of these options are recommended. Even the simplest unsubscribe confirmation email (without the confirmation request) is [seen as bad practice](https://martech.org/the-best-unsubscribe-email-is-the-one-you-dont-send/).